# How do I create a Xamarin button with text AND a background image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

From what I've read, a plain Xamarin button allows text but no background image.  A Xamarin ImageButton allows for an image, but no text.  So how can I get both without shelling out for a SyncFusion licence?

Comment: use a StackLayout with an Image and a Label and add a TapGesture to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grid to put text on ImageButton.
You need to put Label and button  same row.

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center"
  VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
        Source="Xamarin_logo.jpg"
                 Grid.Row="0"/>
      <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
     Text="button"
     TextColor="Purple"
             FontSize="Large"
     Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a ton.